# Colouring greyscale images/sprites for HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html5

What is the best method to colour in sprites at runtime using the canvas element and javascript? I know there are various blending modes using globalCompositeOperation, but I don't know how best to utilise this.

I'll break my question down into the following:

- Is there an optimum way to export greyscale images so they can be easily re-coloured later? (At the moment, the images are created with colour in Photoshop or a similar package and then turned into a greyscale and exported from there before I even touch them)
- With these greyscale images in place, what method makes colouring them with any colour possible? (They must retain the shading etc)

I've tagged this with HTML5 and Javascript, but any advise from other platforms would be helpful.

Edit: Here's an example greyscale output of the image on the left. I want to be able to restore it to the same colour, but also be able to blend it with other colours for different shades of skin.

[image: Greyscale avatar and coloured avatar]

Comment: There is never a *best* solution for a problem. Only the solution which works best for *you*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programatically replace color gradient on sprite](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23740/programatically-replace-color-gradient-on-sprite)

Comment: That's replacing colour programatically, my question is about colouring greyscale images, thanks for the information though. I did mess about with changing HSL values before, but got nowhere, which is why I asked this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you want. The easiest way would be to paint a colorized rectangle above your grayscale image and use one of the following blend-modes: `multiply`, `screen` or `overlay` (which is a combination of screen and multiply).

Here's how these blend-modes look (red rectangle over grayscale image, using multiply, screen and overlay):

[image: colorizing a grayscale image]

The [blend modes](http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2013/01/28/blending-features-in-canvas/) don't seem to be supported in all browsers, so maybe you'd have to implement them yourself. This should be quite straight-forward by iterating through all pixels and mix them with your desired color. Here's a [list of formulas](http://www.deepskycolors.com/archivo/2010/04/21/formulas-for-Photoshop-blending-modes.html) for the most common blend-modes.

Comment: I've implemented all 3 algorithms and tested them but none look right, I assume this would point to the greyscaling process as the problem?

Comment: @totov Well, it really depends what result you're looking for. Maybe you should update your question with a picture/explanation of how your source-image looks like and what result you want, so that we can give better answers?

Comment: To get the perfect results, I had to photoshop the greyscale sprites to reduce the brightness and then applied the overlay blend technique from the article above. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

### Getting the raw pixel data

You can get the raw pixel data with the function `context.getImageData(x, y, width, height)`. The return value is an ImageData structure. This structure will have a field `data` which is an [UInt8ClampedArray](http://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/) where each pixel is represented by four values between 0 and 255 (red, green, blue, alpha).

### Converting an image to greyscale

In order to reduce three color channels (R, G, B) to one, there are different approaches. Which one is the best depends on your use-case.

- Using the highest value (intensity)
- Using the average between the highest and the lowes value (luminosity)
- Using the average of all three (brightness)
- A color-psychological approach: For the human eye, yellow (255, 255, 0) seems brighter than blue (0, 0, 255) and green (0, 255, 0) seems brighter than red (255, 0, 0). You could experiment with a conversion-function which accounts for this.

### Converting greyscale back to color

Depending on which algorithm you decided to use, you will now have a greyscale value between 0 and 255 for each pixel. To converte these to RGB-values depending on your target-colors RGB, there are also different methods.

- Multiplication: A greyscale value of 0 is black, a greyscale value of 255 is equal to your target-color
- Overlay: A greyscale value of 0 is black, a value of 127 is your target-color and a value of 255 is white
- Screen: A greyscale value of 0 is your target-color, a greyscale value of 255 is white

The values in between are interpolated linearly. The best method depends on the effect you are aiming for, what algorihm you've chosen for greyscaling and what your target-color is.

### Writing the raw pixel data back to the canvas

To copy the imagedata structure with the modified array back to the canvas, you can use `context.putImageData(imagedata, x, y)`.

### Some performance considerations

Keep in mind that working with raw image-data is an expensive operation. Usually all canvas operations can be done on the GPU. But in this case the canvas texture must be serialized, copied to RAM, processed by the CPU and then copied back to the video memory. This is quite slow. Usually too slow to do it with everything on the screen and still keep a steady framerate. So when you intend to draw the resulting colored sprite more than once, you should buffer the result of the recoloring on an invisible background-canvas and use this as an image source for `context.drawImage` when the recolored sprite needs to be drawn again.

Comment: The greyscales I'm working with are produced from converting them to greyscales within photoshop, so I don't have much control over the algorithm there. Is it just trial and error with the 3 blending techniques?

Answer (score 3):

Adding to what @Philipp said (especially the "caching blended result"). You can reverse calculate the second image from the `blend(grey,????) = colored` equation for the multiply,overlay and screen functions. The problem is that the range of the `?????` image may be out of the range of `0-255`. So you might need to save them as a different format or encode something like a signed int into the 4 bytes of the RGBA values in one pixel for each channel.

As others said you can also use other color-models for help. HSV is the one that appears to be the obvious choice and it will look like this: [image]

But as you can see the separated saturation and hue image still contains a good amount of the shading information, so a color model like YUV might seem more appropriate. It would look like this: [image]

The problem here is that the inter-relationship that the RGB values in your blending source have with the final image might not always be so apparent.

Using just the raw components of these color models though has the issue of not being able to make image darker whatsoever. So I'd say use the reverse blending modes or combine the other color-spaces with the blending modes to get it done.

**Edit**: to visualize what I meant with the multiplication look at these examples: [image: multiplication example]

The top 2 use multiplication with the regular color spectrum (0-255 mapped to 0-1), you can see that the image can only be made darker, making the red channel bright enough for a natural skin tone is basically impossible within the default spectrum. However if you look at the lower example of brightening it, then you can see that if you multiply it with values over 1 you can once again recreate the original result

Btw. if you're worried about the underwear being colored too, you need to mask it out (just use the grey base image where you don't want any coloration):
[image]

To calculate the scale value lets take for example the gray scale has the color [120 , 120, 120] at one point and the colored image has the color [152 107 74] at the same spot then the scale factors would be s_red = 152/120 = 1.27 , s_green = 107/120 = 0.892 and s_blue = 74/120 = 0.617, so [1.27 0.892 0.617].

You could reasonably map the re-color RGB value from [0-255] to [0-2] or something like that to easier use existing structures as well as limit the brightening to reasonable values. So your setup would look something like this (with the masking applied of course):

[image: mult by color times 2]

Don't forget to clamp your resulting image to [0-255] though.

Comment: to have different shades of skin colour, we'll need the ability to change brightness (or darkness), so don't think these methods could work, but thanks for the information

Comment: @totov like I said, you can easily combine this with multiplication or other blending techniques. The images were mainly an aid to understand how transforming the image into another color-space could be used to separate color from luminosity and recombine them.

Comment: Your method also requires the recolouring source to have shadow information (as you mention above), so apart from having an image with each colour we want to blend with the greyscale (which would be counterproductive to this question), I'm not sure the two colour models above can help. I'd be interested to hear more about mixing multiplication and blending techniques to provide a solution though. Thanks again!

Comment: @totov "Your method also requires the recolouring source to have shadow information" you misunderstood what I tried to demonstrate, your question was "I want to be able to restore it to the same colour, but also be able to blend it with other colours". The color models try to mainly answer the "restore the same color" question. It was supposed to demonstrate different methods of separating color and shading. But anyways, look at the edit for the details doing it by multiplication.